# Face tracking using opencv arduino and python

Tags: python, opencv, arduino

I'm working on face tracking project. I sucessfully coded face detection on python . I need to track my face by webcam. I have arduino for motor control. I couldn't able to track my face, its hard to communicate with arduino. and what code should I use for tracking purpose I have no idea about the axis . please help

Answer (score 0):

[Face Detection in Python Using a Webcam](https://realpython.com/blog/python/face-detection-in-python-using-a-webcam/)

```
import cv2
import sys

cascPath = sys.argv[1]
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascPath)

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
        gray,
        scaleFactor=1.1,
        minNeighbors=5,
        minSize=(30, 30),
        flags=cv2.cv.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE
    )

    # Draw a rectangle around the faces
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything is done, release the capture
video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But you know that you can't use this on an arduino or any other OpenCV likes (image processing library) on any type of micro-controller 
for that matter, since they have very low processor power that is just enough to handle some IO commands but also you may can use some more expensive camera module with built-in face detection on hardware.
to do the face detection ; But with a webcam you would need a ***raspberry pi*** or any other single board pc with enough CPU & GPU to do the job.

and for the communication with python you can go to arduino playground

[Arduino and Python](http://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/Python)

After installing [pySerial](https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial), reading data from Arduino is straightforward:

```
>>> import serial
>>> ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbserial', 9600)
>>> while True:
...     print ser.readline()
'1 Hello world!\r\n'
'2 Hello world!\r\n'
'3 Hello world!\r\n'
```

Comment: thank you for the reply, i have my laptop with python3.5 for face detection. now how i can make serial communication when  face is detected and when face is not detected in both condition. can you please give me the full codes.